# Дивжения по наклонным поверхностяи в Godot (KinematicBody)

Tags: c++, линейная-алгебра, godot

Знакомлюсь с игровым движком Godot. Пробую делать своего игрока на основе KinematicBody. Сцена самого игрока выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее решил описать движения игрока. В целом пока все достаточно просто - есть вектор **направления**, который зависит от того какие кнопки зажаты и от положения камеры. Определяется он примерно вот так в методе `process`:

```
void PlayerController::process(float delta)
{
    (void)delta;

    // Сбросить состояние
    state_ = PlayerState::eWaiting;

    // Вектор направления задаваемого кнопками
    Vector3 movementDir = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

    // Изменить локальный вектор направления в зависимости от нажатых клавиш
    auto input = Input::get_singleton();
    if(input->is_action_pressed("forward")) movementDir += Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    if(input->is_action_pressed("backward")) movementDir += Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    if(input->is_action_pressed("left")) movementDir += Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    if(input->is_action_pressed("right")) movementDir += Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Если направление движения изменяется
    if(movementDir.length_squared() > 0.0f && pCamHor_ != nullptr)
    {
        // Установить направление (направление устанавливается относительно камеры)
        direction_ = Transform(pCamHor_->get_global_transform().basis) * movementDir.normalized();
        // Установить состояние
        state_ = PlayerState::eRunning;
    }
}
```

Положение камеры при этом меняется в `physics_process`, и там же осуществляется само движение. Итоговый вектор скорости по сути получается при помощи умножения вектора направления на скалярное значение скорости. Все в целом хорошо, но как насчет наклонных поверхностей? Я решил проверить, и как ожидалось получилось вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при спуске вниз по наклонной возникают небольшие "подпрыгивания". Я так понял это происходит потому, что вектор скорости не направлен вдоль этой плоскости, и в итоге на небольшое время игрок оказывается оторван от нее, после чего в ход вступает вектор силы тяжести.

Я решил попробовать исправить это путем получения нужного вектора движения, который будет направлен вдоль. Я это сделал следующим образом:

1. Получить ***нормаль*** поверхности
2. Векторно умножить вектор текущего направления на эту нормаль, получив некий вектор ***t***
3. Векторно умножить нормаль на вектор ***t***, получив итоговое направление движения

В коде выглядит как-то так:

```
Vector3 n = get_floor_normal();
Vector3 t = direction_.cross(n);
movementDirection = n.cross(t);
```

Но в итоге ничего не изменилось. Подпрыгивания остались, хотя я даже выводил в консоль этот вектор - и вроде как с ним все впорядке (то есть при движении вниз Y меньше 0, при движении вверх больше 0).

Весь код physics_process выглядит вот так:

```
void PlayerController::physicsProcess(float delta)
{
    // Управление камерой
    if(pCamHor_ != nullptr && pCamVert_ != nullptr)
    {
        // Ограничить угол по вертикали
        camVertAngle_ = Math::clamp(camVertAngle_,camMinVAngle,camMaxVAngle);

        // Новые значения углов зависят от времени между кадрами (интерполяция между старым и новым значением)
        float newHAngle = Math::lerp(pCamHor_->get_rotation_degrees().y,camHorAngle_,delta * camAcceleration);
        float newVAngle = Math::lerp(pCamVert_->get_rotation_degrees().x,camVertAngle_,delta * camAcceleration);

        // Установить новое значение
        pCamHor_->set_rotation_degrees(Vector3(0.0f,newHAngle,0.0f));
        pCamVert_->set_rotation_degrees(Vector3(newVAngle,0.0f,0.0f));
    }

    // Вектор "вверх", определяет пол и стены, задается гравитацией
    Vector3 up = -plrGravityVector.normalized();
    // Направление движения
    Vector3 movementDirection = direction_;
    // Вектор скорости движения
    Vector3 desiredVelocity = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

    // Скорость падения растет если игрок в воздухе
    freeFallVelocity_ = this->is_on_floor() ? Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) :  freeFallVelocity_ + (plrGravityVector * plrGravityAcceleration * delta);

    // Если игрок двигается
    if(state_ == PlayerState::eRunning)
    {
        // Если игрок находится на полу и пол является наклонным
        if(is_on_floor() && up.dot(get_floor_normal()) < 1.0f)
        {
            // Вычислить вектор движения вдоль наклонной поверхности
            Vector3 n = get_floor_normal();
            Vector3 t = direction_.cross(n);
            movementDirection = n.cross(t);
        }

        // Желаемая скорость
        desiredVelocity = movementDirection * plrSpeed;
    }

    velocity_ = desiredVelocity;

    // Двигать объект
    this->move_and_slide(velocity_ + freeFallVelocity_,up);
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Почему вектор скорости направленный вдоль наклонной поверхности не решает эту проблему? Может это какой-то баг движка? А может подобное в godot реализовывается как-то иначе?

Comment: ¿А is_on_floor срабатывает каждый раз?

Comment: @user7860670 is_on_floor действительно срабатывает через раз по каким-то причинам, даже просто на ровной поверхности. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Надо полагать, что is_on_floor сработает при взаимодействии с полом, которое не произойдет, если просто направить объект параллельно полу. Наверное к объекту еще необходимо применить гравитацию или может делать вектор скорости под небольшим наклоном, чтобы объект припечатывался. Или с большой вероятностью это все вообще не нужно и двигать можно по плоскости.

Answer (score 1):

Данную проблему удалось решить лишь при помощи своего метода isOnFloor, поскольку метод is_on_floor у KinematicBody, предлагаемый движком, работает довольно странно и судя по всему это и является причиной данной проблемы.

Выкладываю код своего метода isOnFloor использующего рей-каст, может быть кому-то пригодится.

```
/**
 * \brief Находится ли на полу/земле игрок
 * \param up Вектор вверх
 * \param contactNormal Нормаль в точке соприкосновения с полом
 * \param maxSlopeAngle Максимальный угол поверхности (в радианах)
 * \return Если игрок на поверхности и угол наклона не превышает maxSlopeAngle будет отдано true
 */
bool Player::isOnFloor(const Vector3 &up, Vector3 *contactNormal, float maxSlopeAngle)
{
    // Если есть collision shape
    if(pCollisionShape_ != nullptr)
    {
        // Указатель на форму для коллизии
        auto pCapsuleShape = Object::cast_to<CapsuleShape>(pCollisionShape_->get_shape().ptr());

        // Если capsule shape задан
        if(pCapsuleShape != nullptr)
        {
            // Высота капсулы
            auto capsuleHeight = pCapsuleShape->get_height() + (pCapsuleShape->get_radius() * 2);

            // Исходная и конечная точка для рей-каста (луч направлен вниз из центра collision shape)
            Vector3 srcPoint = pCollisionShape_->get_global_transform().origin;
            Vector3 dstPoint = srcPoint + (-up * ((capsuleHeight / 2.0f) + 0.05f));

            // В исключения для луча необходимо добавить самого игрока и его коллизию
            auto exclude = Array();
            exclude.push_back(this);
            exclude.push_back(pCollisionShape_);

            // Трассировка сцены лучом
            auto spaceState = this->get_world()->get_direct_space_state();
            auto intersection = spaceState->intersect_ray(srcPoint,dstPoint,exclude);

            // Если пересечение было
            if(!intersection.empty())
            {
                // Получить нормаль в точке пересечения
                auto normal = intersection["normal"].operator Vector3();

                // Если угол наклона поверхности в допустимых пределах - считать что игрок на полу
                if(normal.dot(up) >= Math::cos(maxSlopeAngle)){
                    if(contactNormal != nullptr) *contactNormal = normal;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

P.S. Необходимо подключить следующие заголовочные файлы:

```
#include <CollisionShape.hpp>
#include <Shape.hpp>
#include <CapsuleShape.hpp>
#include <World.hpp>
#include <PhysicsDirectSpaceState.hpp>
```